# MS access, including null records in a query to count

Tags: ms-access

Good Morning,

I have a database used to register firefighters for examinations, I would like to export my query of testing sites into a spread sheet or database but I have been running into a simple problem.

I have two tables, tblTestSite and tblMaster

tblTestSite looks like this:

comSiteString // Primary key, Short Text that includes date-time-location (One to many relationship to tblMaster.testSite)

Deadline //Date&Time

Site Address //Short Text

Proctor //Short Text


tblMaster looks like this

ID //Primary Key

testSite // Short Text (This is the field being counted in my query)

departmentName //Short Text

lastName //Short Text

firstName //Short Text

testingLevel //Short Text

Here is the SQL for the query:


SELECT tblTestSite.comSiteString, Count(tblMaster.testSite) AS CountOftestSite

FROM tblTestSite INNER JOIN tblMaster ON tblTestSite.comSiteString = tblMaster.testSite

GROUP BY tblTestSite.comSiteString;

And the result:

Testing Site|Number of tests

Test Site 1 | 12

Test Site 2 | 23


My Desired result would be for the query to show all testing sites, including ones that have not yet had any bookings.

Testing Site|Number of tests

Test Site 1 | 12

Test Site 2 | 23

Test Site 3 | 0

I would like for this to work so that I can easily update our online calendar to show the number of seats remaining at a given test site.  If I can just get my query to include nulls, then I can easily do the rest of the work.

If you are going to give me code to insert, please be very specific as to where the code goes into my access query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Pretty sure you meant Count(Nz(tblMaster.testSite)), no?

Comment: No, I didn't.  But on second thought it's unnecessary because I don't think COUNT will return a null, if there aren't any it would return 0.

Comment: Nope, they want 0s where there aren't any rows in tblMaster. This is an instance where the title of the question seems to be asking something different from the text of the question.

Comment: LEFT JOIN did the trick, thanks guys. I will change the title for others to refer to but Im not exactly sure what to put. Im open to suggestions.